# Will beef bones completely submerged in 50 degree water for 24 hours still be safe to make into stock/

Tags: food-safety

Will the fact that they are covered in water inhibit spoilage?

Comment: 50°C or 50°F? Please always clarify, those are very different...

Comment: @leftaroundabout...fair point, but actually it doesn't matter because both 50 C and 50F place the meat in the danger zone...making this unsafe.

Comment: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/105225/27482

Comment: No, the water will not significantly inhibit spoilage.

Comment: Thank you everyone.  Stephie summed it up.  I appreciate all the input.